Error while setting up JSON Server Auth: Cannot find module json-server
I followed all the necessary steps to run JSON Server, and it starts running perfectly. However, when I try to set up JSON Server Auth using the command:
json-server-auth -w db.json

I encounter the following error:
C:\Users\Ahmad\Downloads\khalid_done\backend>json-server-auth -w db.json
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'json-server'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server-auth\dist\guards.js
- C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server-auth\dist\bin.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server-auth\dist\guards.js:6:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Ahmad\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\json-server-auth\\dist\\guards.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Ahmad\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\json-server-auth\\dist\\bin.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v21.2.0

I followed all the steps properly, including running the following commands:
npm install json-server-auth
npm install json-server
json-server --watch db.json -m ./node_modules/json-server-auth

However, when I run json-server --watch db.json, it starts the localhost on port 3000.
when i run
json-server --watch db.json -m ./node_modules/json-server-auth

it shows error
Unknown option '-m'
Usage: json-server [options] <file>

Options:
 -p, --port <port>  Port (default: 3000)
 -h, --host <host>  Host (default: localhost)
 -s, --static <dir> Static files directory (multiple allowed)
 --help             Show this message
 --version          Show version number


Kindly help me to resolve it and setup auth server.
Thanks in advance!

it starts the localhost on port 3000 what host/port were you expecting? you didn't supply either -p or -h to change the default

simple json server starts but not json server auth. Basically i am new to this and i don't know exact difference. My login register call is not running

instead of -m try --middlewares ... apparently

@JaromandaX the docs have both --middlewares, -m  Paths to middleware files

Which version of json-server have you installed? I suspect you have the v1.0.0-alpha build. Make sure you're using the latest stable version v0.17.4

@Phil - yeah, but maybe the docs are old :p

I'm having the same issue I think we are following the same tutorial https://www.seijivillafranca.com/post/faking-your-auth-endpoint-using-json-server-auth it looks the latest version doesn't implement middlewares, we need to install version 0.17.4

The @jigzat it's correct. You need to install the json-server@0.17.4 to it works. I created a simple example on StackBlitz for you to check. You can register a new user using the terminal on StackBlitz with the curl command. Something like curl --request POST JSON_SERVER_STACKBLITZ_URL/register --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{ "email": "josh@mail.com", "password": "passw0rd" }'. After this the db.json should contain a new user

@marcelofreires Thanku very much fo helping.

You need to install the json-server@0.17.4 to it works. I created a simple example on StackBlitz for you to check. You can register a new user using the terminal on StackBlitz with the curl command. Something like:
curl --request POST JSON_SERVER_STACKBLITZ_URL/register --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{ "email": "josh@mail.com", "password": "passw0rd" }'


JSON_SERVER_STACKBLITZ_URL is the URL where the application is running. You can get this in the preview panel or the sidebar option Ports in use.

After this, the db.json should contain a new user.

Add the following command in the package.json file :
"scripts": {
    "start": "json-server-auth -w db.json",
 }

and then run it :
npm start

